# Tuple's new values not saving outside a foreach loop

Tags: python, foreach, tuples

```
for row in tuple:
    print row[6] # Error: tuple index out of range
    storyLen = len(row[5])
    row = row + (storyLen, )
    print row[6] # No Error as it's added
    # Leave loop now

for newRow in tuple:
    print newRow[6] # Error: tuple index out of range
```

Why does the above happen? Shouldn't the value be saved between the two loops and is there anyway to fix it? If it matters the tuple is a class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that `row` is a "copy" of the actual element of the tuple. So, any change you make won't affect the original tuple. (You can test this by printing the `id`'s)

**What can you do?**

You can loop through indices:

```
for i in range(len(tuple)):
    storyLen = len(tuple[i][5])
    tuple[i] += (storyLen,)
```

This will work because you are *directly accessing* to the elements of the tuple.

**Note:** Don't use `tuple` as a name of a variable since it will hide Python's built-in implementation of the type `tuple`.

Comment: "*What happens is that `row` is a "copy" of the actual element of the tuple. So, any change you make won't affect the original tuple.*" - this is a dangerously misleading statement. The `row` variable refers to the object the tuple cell referred to when the loop iteration started. Assigning to `row` changes what `row` refers to, but it doesn't change the tuple's reference. Also, `tuple[i] += (storyLen,)` won't work, since tuples are immutable.

Comment: @user2357112 Does that mean there is no way to do achieve what I want in the OP? Christian's suggest would work if I were able to add like I do in OP but I guess it only works that way because it's  referencing the values.


EDIT: I assume the way to do it would be to just make it a list.